# Postgres, How can I deny to create a database with a werid name (trailing space, leading space, or even avlid using space in a database name)

Tags: bash, postgresql

I'm trying to add some constraints on database creation command in PostgreSQL.

Currently, I could do

```
psql -c "CREATE database \"     x  y\"\"z'     \""
```

Then, I will get a database named literally `"     x  y"z'     "` (without the double-quotes boundary).
It seems that pgsql supports any characters in it's database name, which is cool.
But it leads me headaches when I am doing automation stuff with bash script.
Yes, some additional work could be done to handle these cases in script. But I think these kind of names are actually meaningless (at least in my situation :), so, is there a way to add some constraints on database naming. For example, only allow [a-zA-Z0-9_.]+.

Comment: No you cannot, same as you cannot restrict users from creating file names with random characters including non-printable. Your only secure reliable option is to deal with it in your script and be safe. It is the sole sane option. If the implementation fail with some database names, then the implementation is faulty, not the database names.

Comment: @LéaGris, thx for commenting. A solid script could avoid system faulty. But, I prefer those databases with weird names not able to exist in the database server, rather than having flawless scripts to handle them. It is a good feature that pgsql allows naming its database arbitrarily, while, I think it is better and it should have a mechanism that pgsql allows user/dba to apply arbitrary constraints as required on its database naming. BTW, I'm not quite understanding the meaning of "sole sane option". Not a native English speaker, sorry :P

Answer (score 1):

Just do not use double quotes, which you should avoid anyway if at all possible.  See [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html):

> SQL identifiers and key words must begin with a letter (a-z, but also
>   letters with diacritical marks and non-Latin letters) or an underscore
>   (_). Subsequent characters in an identifier or key word can be
>   letters, underscores, digits (0-9), or dollar signs ($). Note that
>   dollar signs are not allowed in identifiers according to the letter of
>   the SQL standard, so their use might render applications less
>   portable. The SQL standard will not define a key word that contains
>   digits or starts or ends with an underscore, so identifiers of this
>   form are safe against possible conflict with future extensions of the
>   standard. ... There is a second kind of identifier: the delimited
>   identifier or quoted identifier. It is formed by enclosing an
>   arbitrary sequence of characters in double-quotes ("). A delimited
>   identifier is always an identifier, never a key word.  ... Quoted
>   identifiers can contain any character, except the character with code
>   zero. (To include a double quote, write two double quotes.) This
>   allows constructing table or column names that would otherwise not be
>   possible, such as ones containing spaces or ampersands.

Not doubling quoting in you examples makes those names invalid and Postgres has no problem telling about it. So just do not use them.

Alternately you could create an event trigger. Within there you can restrict object names as needed, esp useful if you have strict naming standards. This would allow for database enforcement of those standards;

```
create function app_validate_table_name()
    returns event_trigger
    language 'plpgsql'
as $$
begin
  if obj.object_identity ~! '[A-Za-z$_][[A-Za-z0-9$_]{0,62}'
  then 
      raise exception 'App Error: Request Name (%) is invalid for <Your App Name here>',obj.object_identity;
  end if
  return;
end ;
$$;

create event trigger app_table_event_trigger on ddl_command_end
    when tag in ('ALTER TABLE', 'CREATE TABLE')
    execute procedure app_validate_table_name();
```

While the same can be applied to other objects it unfortunately does not seem to apply to creating a database itself.  
 
Disclamer: The above has NOT been tested.

Comment: Thank you @Belayer for your answer, but I'm looking for a way to restrict database naming, not naming of objects inside a database instance. I think SQL identifiers and keywords are only in effect on those objects while the database naming constraint should happen before the database creation. I've also referenced the "Event Trigger", it looks promising to solve this issue. However, I cannot find a **Command Tag** named like CREATE DATABASE under the [event trigger firing matrix](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/event-trigger-matrix.html)

Comment: That's why I indicated it seemed to not work for create database. Sorry that didn't help, so back to just NOT using double quotes. But that is beneficial in it own right.